# Remove hyperlink but keep text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/something" title="Show Profile">Mentalist</a>
```

Whenever a hyperlink has a title of "Show Profile" I want to remove the hyperlink and replace it with only with the text.

So instead of

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/something" title="Show Profile">Mentalist</a>
```

I want to have only `Mentalist`.

Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

this should work:

```
$('a[title="Show Profile"]').contents().unwrap();
```

Here a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbHYM/) with the proof.

Comment: unwrap() is pretty neat.  Just for completeness, here's an alternative solution that should also work: $("a[title='Show Profile']").replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); });

Comment: Really clever! +10

Answer (score 4):

Vanilla JavaScript way (instead of jQuery) to remove hyperlink but keep text:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a[title="Show Profile"]')

links.forEach(link => {
    const el = document.createElement('span')
    el.textContent = link.textContent
    link.parentNode.replaceChild(el, link)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/something" title="Show Profile">Mentalist</a>
<a href="http://www.website.com/something" title="Something Else">Mentalist</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("a[title='Show Profile']").each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
</script>
```

It should replace only the first link.

Comment: DanielB has provided a much nicer solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188277/remove-hyperlink-but-keep-text/6188344#6188344

Answer (score 2):

To do this on links of multiple classes,

```
$("a.className1, a.className2").contents().unwrap();
```