# How to remove hyperlink but keep text for an array of links?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove hyperlink but keep text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188277/remove-hyperlink-but-keep-text)

My question is fairly similar to this question: [Remove hyperlink but keep text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188277/remove-hyperlink-but-keep-text) but, I can't seem to workout how I can feed an array of class names and do this in one go?

**For Example**

Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah

I would just like the links with the unwrap class to be modified.

Comment: `$(".unwrap").contents().unwrap();`?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: That's actually the answer, not just a comment.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I know-- I didn't want to answer because I think it's a dupe of the linked question. I'm out of close votes though `:-/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this on multiple classes, you can do

```
 $("a.className1, a.className2").contents().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TW6hn/)**

```
$('a.unwrap').contents().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 2):

The selector `a.unwrap` specifies all `a` elements with class `unwrap`:

```
$('a.unwrap').contents().unwrap();
```

[Example at JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nJVLf/)