# Links are being printed besides the text

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a problem where the link locations are being printed when the user prints. Is there a way to disable the locations from being printed?

For example if I have the following code

```
<div id="link_row" class="headerbar"><a href="admin.aspx">Home</a>
```

it will print Home (admin.aspx)

or on other links Link1(javascript:Do_something()) when I only want to print Link1

Is there something that I can do to avoid such a problem?

[Print a website without printing the link locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476393/print-a-website-without-printing-the-link-locations)

I looked at the link above to, but I am not able to follow the solution there.

Thank you,

Varun

EDIT: Just to clarify that this is occuring across all users with IE 8 or Firefox 3.6.

Comment: Does your site have a print style sheet? Usually you have to explicitly add the functionality you are reporting. Does this happen for all users on all browsers?

Comment: Yes it does use a print style sheet and it occurs across Firefox and Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox 3.6. Also, I do not want the the bracketed text to show and which elements can I use to add the functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[asp.net-mvc includes a default print stylesheet](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/printer_friendly).  It uses a CSS pseudo-elements to add the value of the href into the visible html.  [Css-Tricks has a good article](http://css-tricks.com/9516-pseudo-element-roundup/) on this trick and others.

You should find the CSS selector in the default print stylesheet (probably similar to "a[href]:after"), then add that same selector to your own print stylesheet, and make it override the original, which may require using !important.

```
@media print {
  a[href]:after { content: ""; }
  }
```

*or*, if that doesn't work:

```
@media print {
  a[href]:after { content: "" !important; }
  }
```