# Need to remove href values when printing in Chrome

Tags: css, printing, hyperlink, print-css

I'm attempting to customize the print CSS, and finding that it prints links out with the `href` value as well as the link.

This is in Chrome.

For this HTML:

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

It prints:

```
Google (http://www.google.com)
```

And I want it to print:

```
Google
```

Comment: Keep in mind WHY every major CSS framework does that - you can't click on paper! So if you're going to deactivate it you should add a list of links at the bottom, such as this: https://alistapart.com/article/improvingprint

Comment: That's true, but I think it's better to have control of when and where the link appears. For instance, in my links I want them to appear in the next line after the text, and without parentheses. So I just show the url in the text.

Answer (score 626):

Bootstrap does the same thing (... as the selected answer below).

```
@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
  }
}
```

Just remove it from there, or override it in your own print stylesheet:

```
@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: `<style>@media print{a[href]:after{content:none}}</style>` Mostly posting for myself when I keep coming back to this page, thank you

Comment: Apparently Foundation does the samething too.

Comment: Looks like **HTML5 Boilerplate** also does this! So I guess I have to override it through code change on my own website, and through Inspector on other websites...

Comment: Warning: We had issues where a table sometimes lost the last few rows when printing. Turned out that this rule was the culprit, or at least removing it fixed the issue. Do not know why it had that effect.

Comment: After digging more, I don't think that this was the only factor. While removing it fixed the issue, removing it AND all of Bootstrap print reintroduced the issue…

Comment: @HenrikN - i think that's related to bootstrap columns floating. using `float:none` where necessary fixed a similar issue for me a few weeks back; might help you, but that's a different issue

Answer (score 41):

[It doesn't](http://jsfiddle.net/3yDzY/show/). Somewhere in your print stylesheet, you must have this section of code:

```
a[href]::after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")"
}
```

The only other possibility is you have an extension doing it for you.

Comment: I got it in zurb foundation css.

Answer (score 29):

```css
@media print {
   a[href]:after {
      display: none;
      visibility: hidden;
   }
}
```

Work's perfect.

Answer (score 10):

If you use the following CSS

```
<link href="~/Content/common/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"    />
<link href="~/Content/common/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/common/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

just change it into the following style by adding **media="screen"**

```
<link href="~/Content/common/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" **media="screen"** type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/common/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" **media="screen"** type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/common/site.css" rel="stylesheet" **media="screen"** type="text/css" />
```

I think it will work.

the former answers like

```
    @media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: none !important;
  }
}
```

were not worked well in the chrome browse.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered a similar problem only with a nested img in my anchor:

```
<a href="some/link">
   <img src="some/src">
</a>
```

When I applied

```
@media print {
   a[href]:after {
      content: none !important;
   }
}
```

I lost my img and the entire anchor width for some reason, so instead I used:

```
@media print {
   a[href]:after {
      visibility: hidden;
   }
}
```

which worked perfectly.

*Bonus tip*: [inspect print preview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29962072/5211269)

Answer (score 3):

To hide Page url .

use `media="print"` in style tage example :

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
            @page {
                size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
                margin: 0;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
            }
            @page { size: portrait; }
</style>
```

If you want to remove links :

```
@media print {
   a[href]:after {
      visibility: hidden !important;
   }
}
```

Comment: You should use `display: none !important;` if you want to get rid of the space the URL would occupy on the page.

Answer (score 0):

For normal users. Open the inspect window of current page.
And type in:

```
l = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i =0; i<l.length; i++) {
    l[i].href = "";
}
```

Then you shall not see the url links in print preview.

Comment: This is a good solution if you have no control over the source code of the page you are trying to print.