# Remove links references from the Media Print Screen

Tags: html, css

I' am having a small issue where I cannot remove the link reference from the print view.

**This is what I can on my HTML side**

```
<table style="width: 436px; height: 374px;" border="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color: #edfbef;">
            <td><span style="color: #3366ff;"><a title="Electricity Tariffs and Rates" href="http://newfea.oceanic.net.fj/your-home/electricity-tariffs-and-rates/"><span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Electricity Tariff &amp; Rates</strong></span></a></span></td>
            <td>Find out how you are being charged for the power you use at home</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**This is what I have on my header.php page for media queries**

```
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/resources/css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
```

**Here is a snapshot how it looks in normal HTML View**
[image: HTML VIEW]

**Here is the Media Print Vision**
[image]

You can see from the print view there are the link reference of the links. Is there a way I can remove this using CSS.

I have tried **display: none**, **visibility: hidden**, its doesn't because it hides the whole link text with it.

Comment: @3dgoo I haven't used any of them, Its my custom theme.

Comment: Similar question asked before. Better check this link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301989/need-to-remove-href-values-when-printing-in-chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: none !important;
  }
}
```

Try to override your `print media` by the above code.

Answer (score 2):

REFERENCE LINK : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepvirani/6hVF4/)

```
<span class="printonly"><strong>Electricity Tariff &amp; Rates</strong></span>
```

ADD THIS NEW SPAN ABOVE TD.

### [NOTE : ADDING CLASS "printonly" to NEW <td> for PRINT ONLY.]

---

WE WILL HIDE BELOW TD WHILE PRINTING USING ATTACHED CSS

### [NOTE : ADDING CLASS "withoutprint" to your <td> ]

```
  <span class="withoutprint" style="color: #3366ff;">
     .....
       .....
```

---

### CSS

```
.printonly{
    display:none;
}
    @media print {
    .withoutprint{
        display: none;
    }
    .printonly{
        display:block;
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These links are placed there by your stylesheet. I am guessing you have used a theme or [boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/main.css).

Check the print styling in these stylesheets.

You are looking for something like this:

```css
a[href]:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}
```

You would want to remove that.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

**CSS:**

```
@media only print {
    a { text-decoration: none; color: black; cursor: default; }
}

@media only screen {
    a { cursor: pointer; }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/WJSZ3/show/light/)