# How to remove url (shown after links) from a printed page (Chrome)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

**Not referring to the URL at top of page.**

When an `<a>` tag is printed in Chrome, it shows the URL after it.

Instead of just showing the anchor text (like this: `StackOverflow`)

It shows the anchor text w/ URL after it

(like this: `StackOverflow (window.open('www.stackoverflow.com'))`

This makes the printed page stretch off the printable area, and I'm trying to avoid this from happening.  Can this setting be disabled somehow in printing mode or is there a `@media print` style that can be defined to remove this URL part from print screen?

Comment: May I ask, is that the javascript method of opening a new window rather than using `target="_blank"`?

Comment: i don't see that - perhaps its an option that you have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to remove href values when printing in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301989/need-to-remove-href-values-when-printing-in-chrome)

Comment: @MackieeE Yes, its to open a new window, but its only an example.  There is much longer JS code in there that stretches off the page that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 14):

Tell it not to print anything after the anchor tag.

```
@media print {
    a:after { content:''; }
    a[href]:after { content: none !important; }

}
```

Comment: Why does it need 2 CSS items? It seems 1st one will print empty string (nothing), which is effectively equal to 2nd one ...

Comment: the second definition is an override in case your using a framework such as Bootstrap which uses this selector.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this,

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page {
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
}
</style>
```