# Relative URL when printing with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, url, printing

when I try to print (ctrl+P) a page of my site made with cakePhp and bootstrap I have all relatives urls (between parenthesis) printed in the page  (See example in joined image)

[image]

Could you help please to avoid these URL in the printed page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to remove href values when printing in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301989/need-to-remove-href-values-when-printing-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not CakePHP realted question, to avoid your problem you must play with css print media type

Here is answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14931127/1127933

Comment: Thank you a lot it was infact bootstrap media print ;)