# How to hide the action link printed at the bottom of each image

Tags: css, printing

My page contains several images:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="img/16.jpg"><img src="img/16.jpg" class="center-block img-responsive"></a>
```

When I print my page (chrome), the href is visible at the bottom of each image.

**So, how to hide the action link printed at the bottom of each image, please?**

When I apply, by example, the class 'hidden-print' to the action block then my image disappeared...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not reproduce the problem on chrome, so i guess its not because of anchor tag. And as Jackson already said, you might have,

```
a:after {
   content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}
```

in any of your css framework if you have used.

> if you're using Twitter Bootstrap as a framework, this will work for
>   you(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14931127/3556874):

```
a[href]:after{
    content:"";
}
```

> If you are not sure , where is it written or if you can not change the
>   external css, you will also require to consider the `:before` pseudo
>   class

```
@media print{

 a[href]:after{
        content:"";
    }
 a[href]:before{
        content:"";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's common to include a print.css file which is used when the webpage is printed. This file probably contains a style for all anchor tags to output the href after the link.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

Inside the css file you might find a style value for the a tag like this:

```
a:after {
   content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}
```

Removing this style might fix your problem.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
@media print {
     .fancybox {
         color: transparent;
     }
}
```

Media will only trigger on printing a page.
Transprent color will ofcource not be printed.