# Twig links being displayed in generated PDF

Tags: php, symfony, twig, wkhtmltopdf

**EDIT: If you are using Bootstrap, then it is most likely the reason for this problem. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301989/need-to-remove-href-values-when-printing-in-chrome).**

I'm trying to generate a PDF of a twig template using [KnpSnappyBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle).

The problem is that the generated PDF is displaying the actual link in addition to the link text for all links when it is generated, like in this image:[image]

Is there an option for this within wkhtmltopdf? I've looked at the options using `wkhtmltopdf -H` and neither `disable-external-links` nor `disable-internal-links` resolves this.

Here is the code I'm using to generate the PDF:

```
$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->generateFromHtml(
        $this->renderView(
            $template,
            array(
                $key => $array
            )
        ),
        $this->container->getParameter("upload_dir") . '/' . $file,
        array(
            "print-media-type" => true,
            "disable-external-links" => true,
            "disable-internal-links" => true
        )
    );
```

And the HTML:

```
<a href="{{ path('work_descriptions') }}#{{ value.descriptionId }}" target="_blank" class="work-link"><strong><u>{{ title }}</u></strong></a>
```

And yes, I know the `{{ title }}` value does not include the actual link because when I use it outside of a link tag, the PDF displays it fine.

I'm trying my best to avoid hacky solutions, but I'm not sure what the problem is.

UPDATE: The problem happens regardless of whether twig variables are used or not.

Comment: what happens if you don't disable internal/external links?

Comment: The only thing the disable external/internal links option does is remove the ability to click on links in the PDF, the text unfortunately remains the same either way.

Comment: I've had this exact issue before and I cannot remember what the issue was.  Is the link you gave a valid anchor in the document?

Comment: Yes, not getting any HTML validation errors regarding it either. Absolute URLs make no difference as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was adding another variable to send to the template to let it know when the template was going to be used for a PDF, then run the appropriate JavaScript to remove the links after checking if the variable is defined.

In PDF generation action:

```
$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->generateFromHtml(
            $this->renderView(
                "my-template.html.twig",
                array(
                    "templateData" => array(
                        "data" => $session->get("templateData"),
                        "pdf" => true //<--------- Check this variable in template
                    )
                ),
            ),
            $this->container->getParameter("upload_dir") . '/' . $file,
            array(
                "print-media-type" => true,
                "disable-external-links" => true,
                "disable-internal-links" => true
            )
);
```

In Twig:

```
{% if templateData.pdf is defined %}
   <script>
      $(".work-link").each(function()
      {
         $(this).prop("href", "#");
      });
   </script>
{% endif %}
```

This seems to be working okay for now.