# How to remove name of controllers in links in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2013, printing

I am using VS 2013 community. I don`t know what to call this but i am facing a strange problem. When i print a page(which is razor view) in Google chrome, i get names of controllers along with links. How do i remove them from prints?

In the image, i have highlighted controller names in yellow. They do not appear in normal operation. When i press ctrl+p they appear in print preview.

[image: Yellow highlight]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to remove href values when printing in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301989/need-to-remove-href-values-when-printing-in-chrome). Your problem is in `css`.

Answer (score 2):

According to comment by @Ivan Gritsenko, i edited bootstrap in my project, and it is working. You have to go to

1. Solution explorer
2. Click on contents and then open bootstrap.
3. find  `" (" attr(href) ")";` and then replace with `none !important;`
4. This should work. You may need to open the new page in incognito mode or private window to load new bootstrap.