# Print CSS avoid URL showing

Tags: css, printing

Is there any way to prevent URL showing when I am printing a webpage?
Actually all  tag shows URL which is much annoying to some client. And my client asked me to avoid URL when printing a page. But I didn't found any solution yet. Tried couple of method already. No result.

Anyone can give me some suggestion is there any way to prevent URL actually?

Comment: Plenty of results already on the site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301989/need-to-remove-href-values-when-printing-in-chrome

Comment: Oh, it's Bootstrap that does that? Great, I was just about to close as unclear.

Comment: Thanks..that helped :)