# Remove URL from printing page using css

Tags: html, css, printing

```
<body>
 <div class="print-logo">
  <img class="print-logo img-responsive" id="logo" src="http://logo.png" alt="image" /></div>
    <div class="print-site_name">Published on <em class="placeholder">website name</em> (<a href="http://localhost">http://localhost</a>)</div>
<p />
<div class="print-breadcrumb"><a href="/">Home</a> Reportedly Prepping </div>
<hr class="print-hr" />
    <div class="print-content"><article id="node-ID" class="node node-blog clearfix">   
<div class="bd-headline left"> some title  </div>    
<div class="item-body">
 <p dir="ltr"><span id="docs-internal-guid-???">    
  <img alt="Core" height="366" src="http://image.png" width="645" />  
   <span> contributor helping  report. It’s the latest nightmare.</span><a href="http://url-to-be-removed">some text for the url to be removed(http://url-to-be-removed) then some more text.  
 </p>   
 <p> some more text and another url</p>
</div>   
...
```

Using CSS how can remove the URL. Since the URL are in the body I tried using the class name and html tag :

```
div.print-content article.node .node-blog .clearfix div.item-body p a { content: "";}
```

**update**
The part i want to remove is in **bold**.
   contributor helping  report. It’s the latest nightmare.[some text for the url to be removed **(http://url-to-be-removed**](http://url-to-be-removed)) then some more text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to remove href values when printing in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301989/need-to-remove-href-values-when-printing-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a[href]:after { content: none !important; }`

**update**

The CSS :after selector inserts something after the content of each selected element(s).

Use the content property to specify the content to insert. `content: none` is for explicitly preventing the `after` selector (pseudo-element) from being generated (really only used to override another style that would have generated content).

`a[href]:after { content: none !important; }` will mean remove content after each link.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the URL from a printed media, use:

```
@media print {
  div.print-content article.node .node-blog .clearfix div.item-body p a {
    display: none;
}
```

If what you want instead is to have it dissapear completely (from any view), just add `div.print-content article.node .node-blog .clearfix div.item-body p a { display: none; }`

Adding it this way will remove it completely from the view of the doc, freeing up any space occupied by the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Thanks what i did is : `div.print-content article.node div.item-body p a { display: none; }` but it remove everything: the link and the url. I update my question and bolded the part that need to be removed which is the URL after the link in parenthesis.