# How to print plain text without showing its hyperlink

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Good day! I was trying to output a generated links from a given array and it was successful. The problem that confuses me is that when I try to click control print ( ctrl + P ) to print the page, it also shows the entire hyperlink, should i change my php code or is it done in html? and also i am using bootstrap 3. When i test other live pages it doesn't do that. What should I do? Thank you.

this is a snippet from my code

```
foreach($array as $key) {

    echo '<td ><a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/">'.$key.'</a></td>';

}
```

the preview in printer shows it like this:

```
1 ( http://example.com/ )
2 ( http://example.com/ )
```

what i need is only the plain text:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Modify your printing options not to print the URLs? But seriously, you may have to do this with CSS. I can't remember how I used to do it, it's been a long time, but it can be done.

Comment: Can you explain further? Please also print the content of your $array

Comment: but why are the other live pages don't act like that., do they have a script that will auto modify the printing options of the user?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476393/print-a-website-without-printing-the-link-locations

Comment: @BelgianMyWaffle Pretty much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my question but anyway thank you for all your opinions and suggestions. I appreciate it. 
It is a bootstrap issue and this link answers my problem.

```
@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: "";
  }
}
```

https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-40321

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    @page 
    {
    a[href]::after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")"
}
    }
</style>
```